# Range of mobius function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ a mobius function such that $ad-bc<0$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$ and denote $$A=\{z\in\mathbb C : Im(z)\geq0\}$$

What is the range $f(A)$?

I thought either to choose an arbitrary point $w=u+vi$ and find $z\in A$ that gives $f(z)=w$. Then, prove that the condition on the coefficients hold. But this gets very technical and I don't understand what guarantees the existance of a result. Since the condition is in terms of inequality, I believe there should be better arguments than just crunching the algebra, which gets very cumbersome...

Comment: Are $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ real, or are they complex numbers so that $ad-bc$ is real and negative? Oh, and better write $w=u+vi$ or something, since $a$ and $b$ are already taken.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thank you, important comments, and I corrected the post correspondingly

Comment: Do you know what Möbius transformations do with straight lines and circles?

Comment: @DanielFischer It transforms them again to straight lines and circles

Comment: Good. And if the coefficients are real, to what line or circle is $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ mapped?

Comment: @DanielFischer to the line $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$

Comment: And since Möbius transformations are biholomorphic maps from the sphere to itself, that leaves only two possibilities for what $f(A\cup \{\infty\})$ could be. Which?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok now I'm a little unsure. Because I don't know the actual reasons. I guess that the positive and negative half-planes?

Comment: Yes. The complement of $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ has two connected components. Since Möbius transformations are continuous, their images are again connected. Since Möbius transformations are bijective, their images together make up the complement of the image of $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$. Thus the image of the open upper half-plane is contained in either the upper or the lower half-plane, and the image of the lower half-plane is contained in the other. By surjectvity, the "contained in" is actually "equal to".

Comment: So determine whether the upper half-plane is mapped to the upper or to the lower half-plane. Checking $f(z)$ for one $z$ with $\operatorname{Im} z > 0$ suffices. Then, since the exercise made the unfortunate decision to consider the closure of the half-plane without $\infty$, you need to see what point $\infty$ is mapped to and remove that from $\mathbb{R}$ (unless $f(\infty) = \infty$).

Comment: In addition to the useful comments already given, you may still learn from some explicit calculations: Multiply numerator and denominator by $c\bar z+d$. The new denominator will be $|cz+d|^2$, and it is now straightforward to find the imaginary part of the numerator (bearing in mind that $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are real).